# can we open a PowerPoint file in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, powerpoint

I am developing an iPhone application where I want to open a PowerPoint file in my application. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Help you out how?  Write the app for you?

Comment: No need to write the app... U can just guide me how to proceed.. That will be good..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-[UIWebView loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:]`

```
[webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the iPhone only currently reads Word and Excel documents. I don't think PowerPoint is supported. I tried it, and it wouldn't open the PowerPoint file.
For a Word file, the iPhone actually has an arrow that you can tap, opening the document in another window.

Comment: iPhone opens PPT files just fine, both from email and from iDisk. I do not know of a way to access this functionality from within a custom app, though.